# Does a PC lycanthrope druid gain a lycanthrope's immunities in humanoid form, and while Wild Shaped?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage-resistance, immunities, lycanthropy

I am a DM playing through *Out of the Abyss* and have chosen to use Topsy and Turvy as pre-made characters for my players. I want them to be druids with the desire to control their lycanthropy.

The rules seem to imply that the damage immunity provided by [lycanthropy](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/mm/monsters-l#Werewolf) affects the humanoid form as well (MM, p. 207).

> A character who becomes a lycanthrope retains his or her statistics
> except as specified by lycanthrope type. The character gains the
> lycanthrope’s speeds in nonhumanoid form, damage immunities, traits,
> and actions that don’t involve equipment.

**Does a PC lycanthrope in humanoid form gain the resistances associated with the lycanthrope?** The placement of the commas in the above excerpt seem to indicate yes.

Comment: Re: my edit, I’ve removed the second question - it was a totally different question from the first and the accepted answer didn’t even address it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Yes, their lycanthropic immunities persist.

Topsy and Turvey have a lot of immunities, which I admittedly forgot about when

> my players left them unsupervised with Buppido and found both of them dead.

Their basic stat blocks as NPC companions include their damage immunities as wererats, as well as their abilities as deep gnomes.

Stats for the Twins:

> **Topsy and Turvy**
>
> **Small humanoids** (deep gnome wererats)
>
> ....
>
> **Damage Immunities:** bludgeoning, piercing and slashing damage from nonmagical weapons that aren't silvered
>
> ....
>
> **Stone Camouflage.** The gnome has advantage on Dexterity (Stealth) checks made to hide in rocky terrain.
>
> **Gnome Cunning.** The gnome has advantage on Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma saving throws against magic.
>
> ....
>
> **Bite.** Melee Weapon Attack .... If the target is a humanoid, it must succeed on a DC 11 Constitution saving throw or be cursed with wererat lycanthropy.

So, from their stat block, we can see that they gain both the features of a deep gnome (stone camouflage and gnome cunning), AND the bite attack and damage immunities of a wererat.

Comment: Great! I appreciate the fast response. I was pretty sure about question 1. I got an answer in the beyond forums from a moderator who agrees with my interpretation with regard to question 2 as well. Always happy when I get it right :)

Comment: @BMM While it's great that you got a quick answer to your question. It is often a good idea to wait at least 24 hours before marking the accepted answer. That encourages more users to weigh in on the topic. Though this isn't a rule and if someone thoroughly answers your question feel free to ignore it.

Comment: @BMM is the discussion with this moderator public? If so, please link it here for future visitors.

Comment: I think this link works, let me know if not. https://www.dndbeyond.com/forums/dungeons-dragons-discussion/rules-game-mechanics/29695-lycanthropy-and-wild-shape#c2